# Builder Annotation not working in Java class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, lombok

---

This code was written for learnig purpose.
@Builder and @Data annotation has been implemented in the Book class. While trying to create a builder for the same in LibraryApplication.java builder is not being recognized.

How can I enable the annotations which on Book class

**Edit **: When trying to compile below error is generated.
      java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: The method builder() is undefined for the type Book at com.baeldung.LibraryApplication$DataSetup.run(LibraryApplication.java:25)

Also I am using STS implementation of eclipse. I have checked whether the same code works in eclilpse Oxygen but the same error is thrown

Note: The project is created in Spring Boot

Book.class

```
package com.baeldung.domain;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;

import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;


@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@Builder
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Book {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@NotNull
String name, isbn;

}
```

LibraryApplication.java

```
package com.baeldung;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationArguments;
import org.springframework.boot.ApplicationRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import com.baeldung.domain.Book;
import com.baeldung.repo.BookingRespository;

@SpringBootApplication
public class LibraryApplication {

@Autowired
private BookingRespository bookingRespository;

@Component
class DataSetup implements ApplicationRunner{

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
//             bookingRespository.save(Book.builder().name("Way of Kings").isbn("123").build());

    }

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(LibraryApplication.class, args);
}

}
```

BookingRepository.java

```
package com.baeldung.repo;

import org.springframework.data.repository.PagingAndSortingRepository;
import org.springframework.data.rest.core.annotation.RepositoryRestResource;

import com.baeldung.domain.Book;

@RepositoryRestResource(path="books",collectionResourceRel="books")
public interface BookingRespository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Book, Long>{

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.baeldung</groupId>
<artifactId>library</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>library</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
        <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.assertj</groupId>
                <artifactId>assertj-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>27.0.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>


</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: I dont see any code that utilizes the builder pattern. What exception do you get?

Comment: I have edited the LibraryApplication.java to show the changes. The exception which I get is "The method builder() is undefined for the type Book"

Comment: And what is the exception or compilation error? What IDE are you using? You need to install lombok into your IDE.

Comment: When trying to compile below error is generated.java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method builder() is undefined for the type Book

 at com.baeldung.LibraryApplication$DataSetup.run(LibraryApplication.java:25).                     Also I am using STS implementation of eclipse. I have checked whether the same code works in eclilpse Oxygen but the same error is thrown.@f1sh

Comment: Also it is my understanding lombok jar is automatically installed once I have specified it in the pom.xml. Am I correct ?

Comment: If you use `mvn package`, this should work. But to get it to work in your IDE (which is probably where you get this error), you need to install lombok into eclipse: https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. It is working in eclispse now.  but not working in STS.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per suggestion by @f1sh - If you use mvn package, this should work. But to get it to work in your IDE (which is probably where you get this error), you need to install lombok into eclipse: projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Installing the Lombok plugin in our IDE is necessary in order to use any annotations from Lombok. I sincerely hope it works for you. and You won't run into any issues.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the lombok jar.

https://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=org/projectlombok/lombok/1.18.4/lombok-1.18.4.jar.

2. Execute in cmd prompt, like open cmd prompt in jar location.
   run java -jar jarname.
3. Restart the IDE, It will work fine.

Answer (score -1):

1.Download the lombok jar file from here and configured with your ide.

lombok jar file download link : https://projectlombok.org/download

2. Then restart your IDE, it will work fine.
3. If still not working then try to clean your project.